# mediaelement don't show play video after 2 sec. in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I have a problem with Mediaelement js for play video(ext.: .m3u8). My slider has multi video that could be play videos.
My problem: When i clicked on play image in every video, only show 2 sec. video and after that my video is hide.

please help me :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access data on a computer (`https://ir13.live21.ir`) different from your host (`http://localhost:4200`). At this point some CORS security settings built into the browser kick in. They require the server to provide an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that lists the allowed origins (i.e. hosts) that can access this resource.
If you can't adapt the server's configuration you could use a proxy server to access the video files.